# Translate not working in contentPane in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile, worklight-studio

I'm creating an app and breaking the main html up into subsequent htmls as recommended in the worklight education.  So the child/page is contained in a separate html snippet that is included via a contentpane.  I'm using the translate function as well.  The translation in the main html works but does not in the html snippet.  Using the code below what I get on the worklight common view is:

- header text comes fine
- button 0 and button 1 text comes fine
- button 2 (the one in the imbedded snippet), text does not come in from the translation

Any help would be greatly welcomed.

snippet from main html

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading">
        <div id="appHeader" class="translate"></div>
    </div>
    <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button">button0</button>
    <br>
    <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button"><div id="button1" class="translate"></div></button>
    <br>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ContentPane" href="views/button2.html"></div>
</div>
```

views/button2.html

```
<button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button"><div id="button2" class="translate"></div></button>
```

messages.js

```
Messages = {
    appHeader : "Translation Test",
    button1 : "translated button 1",
    button2 : "translated button 2"
};
```

Comment: Please add link to the relevant Worklight education article.

Answer (score 1):

Since you break the html to mutli-ones, the default translate will not work. Please reference globalization white paper to do translation. [Worklight Globalization White Paper](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/dev/c_globalization_in_javascript_fr.html)

Comment: is there a sample application that can be downloaded.  not having much luck getting dojo to recognize the translations.  I get "Application did not define an i18n messages object, skipping translation." message in the console

Comment: Eric, may I further know why breaking the html into multi-ones cannot work? As it is still a single page application .. thanks!

Comment: Even though it is one html, there are still a number of views in the app.  So we want to break up the app because of the number of views in the app and the size of the development team.  I liken it to why you do not put most of your java application into one java file.  Allows for multiple developers to work on the app at one time.